# How to change content of 2 childs when hover 1 child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

what I am trying to accomplish is fairly simple but complicated for me to complete. I am trying to hover on 1 child while the other 2 change background colors. And do the same for all 3 children.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="servhold">
    <div class="serv">
        <h1>Clean</h1>
        <p>test test test test test test test
            test test test test test test test
            test test test test test test test
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="serv">
        <h1>Creative</h1>
        <p>test test test test test test test
            test test test test test test test
            test test test test test test test
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="serv">
        <h1>Responsive</h1>
        <p>test test test test test test test
            test test test test test test test
            test test test test test test test
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code (I Tried):

```
.servhold .serv:hover:nth-child(1) + .serv:nth-child(n+2){
    background-color: pink;
}
// hover 1 change background 2+3
.servhold .serv:hover:nth-child(2) + .serv:nth-child(1) , .serv:nth-child(3){
    background-color: pink;
}
// hover 2 change background 1+3
.servhold .serv:hover:nth-child(3) + .serv:nth-child(1) , .serv:nth-child(2){
    background-color: pink;
}
// hover 3 change background 1+2
```

Any help would be appreciated (Javascript or Jquery is fine too.)

Thank you.

Comment: You mean like, while 'creative' is on hover, 'clean' and 'responsive' gets a differen background?

Comment: Yes somewhat like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery** way would be: 
**First function**-changing `siblings background`.
**Second function**- restarting the `siblings background`-Put there your original `background-color` instead of `initial`

```js
$('.servhold .serv').hover(function() {

  $(this).siblings('.serv').css('background-color', 'pink');

}, function() {

  $(this).siblings('.serv').css('background-color', 'initial');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="servhold">

  <div class="serv">
    <h1>Clean</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="serv">
    <h1>Creative</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="serv">
    <h1>Responsive</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works just like I wanted it to! I'm giving you the answer because you provided the code and the snippet. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I think you're saying you want this:

*Better view here:* https://jsfiddle.net/wsbLy0b2/1/

```css
.servhold:hover .serv {
  background-color: pink;
}

.servhold:hover .serv:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="servhold">

  <div class="serv">
    <h1>Clean</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="serv">
    <h1>Creative</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="serv">
    <h1>Responsive</h1>
    <p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `:hover` on the `.servhold` turns them all pink, but the `:hover` on the `.serv` sets the specific one to `transparent` so the outer background shows through. You can set it to a different color if desired.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although I do want all of them to begin with a white background(not with pink). I'd appreciate if you edit your answer, thanks.

Comment: @Graphicoding: They do begin with a white background.

Comment: What I mean was that I don't want to hover on `.servhold` and make my `.serv` pink. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the hover event to the class '.serv' and then add pink background to all the elements and making the background transparent on the element on which the hover function is called

```
$('.serv').hover(function(){
    $('.serv').css({'background-color': 'pink'});
    $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
});
```

Comment: Good concept, will try it as soon as possible and declare the answer to whoever I feel has the best answer. Thanks.